# Publish SOAP in a Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, soap, xsd

Is there someone who see what im doing worng here?
Im trying to use this script in my asp site.
$z:value[article.number] is my art.number in my asp.
My intention when i click on my article i will see the picture.

Best Regards
Frank

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var symbol = "MSFT"; 
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no/ProduktInfo.asmx?op=HentBildeLenkeTyped",true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
  alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  var json = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(xmlhttp.responseXML);
  var result = json.Body[0].HentBildeLenkeTypedResponse[0].HentBildeLenkeTypedResult[0].Text;
  json = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(XMLObjectifier.textToXML(result));
  alert(SModulNr + ' ProduktInfo: $' + json.Stock[0].Last[0].Text); 
 }
}
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no/HentBildeLenkeTyped");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
 '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
                'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
                'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' + 
   '<soap:Body> ' +
     '<HentBildeLenkeTyped xmlns="http://produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no/"> ' +
       '<sModulNr> + $z:value[article.number] + </sModulNr> '+
       '<iSize>xlarge</iSize> '+
     '</HentBildeLenkeTyped> ' +
   '</soap:Body> ' +
 '</soap:Envelope>';
xmlhttp.send(xml);

</script>
```

**This is the orginal from my provider.**

```
POST /ProduktInfo.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <HentBildeLenkeTyped xmlns="http://produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no/">
      <sModulNr>string</sModulNr>
      <iSize>None or small or large or xlarge or original or largeThumbnail</iSize>
    </HentBildeLenkeTyped>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <HentBildeLenkeTypedResponse xmlns="http://produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no/">
      <HentBildeLenkeTypedResult>string</HentBildeLenkeTypedResult>
    </HentBildeLenkeTypedResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
'<sModulNr>$z:value[article.number]</sModulNr>  '
```

is where you're going wrong.  You're literally requesting the value "$z:value[article.number]" instead of the article number you want.

It's not clear exactly to me what $z is from what you've posted, but you probably want something more along the lines of

```
'<sModulNr>' + $z:value[article.number] + '</sModulNr>'
```

Comment: Thanks, Tested but with same result. I get an dialogbox with OK button, but nothing "good" happend. When i use $z:value[article.number] in other JS it works like a charm.

Comment: Start logging the exact data you are sending, and the data you are receiving. This will help you get to the bottom of the problem.  Are you using Chrome/Firefox/Safari?  If so, change your code to this:    console.debug(xml); xmlhttp.send(xml); You can then inspect the actual string  you're sending.  Here is some help on this for Chrome: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console .  Similarly, log the result: ( console.debug(xmlhttp.responseText); alert(xmlhttp.responseText); ) so we can see what's being returned...